# two x axes in the same graph?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, graph, core-plot

How to draw two x axes in the same graph when drawing with core-plot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 CPXYAxis *topX = [[[CPXYAxis alloc] init] autorelease];
 CPXYAxis *bottomX = [[[CPXYAxis alloc] init] autorelease];
 CPXYAxis *y = [[[CPXYAxis alloc] init] autorelease];

 topX.coordinate = CPCoordinateX;
 bottomX.coordinate = CPCoordinateX;

 y.coordinate = CPCoordinateY;

 CPAxisSet *axisSet = [[[CPAxisSet alloc] init] autorelease];
 axisSet.axes = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:topX,bottomX,y,nil];
 graph.axisSet = axisSet;
```

You might need multiple plot spaces, each of on x axis..[CPTestApp](http://code.google.com/p/core-plot/source/browse/#hg/examples/CPTestApp/Source) example creates multiple y axis, which will help you..Hope this helps..

Comment: Thank you so much dude! Got the second axis in the same plotSpace. The example gives a lot of insights. Now going forward, do we need to manually map the value to the plot or how to link the new axis to a plot? I mean drawing one bar with old axis and one bar with new axis.